# VB .Net Add strings on the beginning and the end of every line of a textbox

Tags: string, textbox, builder

I am trying to figure out how to:

I have a textbox with 3 words like this,

Word1
Word2
Word3

Now im trying to find a solution how by pressing a button to convert text above to this

'Word1',
'Word2',
'Word3'

Best Regards

Comment: that means you want to separate each words with comma`,`

Comment: Hmmm editor didn't show my words as i expected. Word1 is on first line, Word2 is on the second line and Word3 is on the third line.What i want to do is to put '' on every line and seperate them with a comma ,

Comment: 'Word1',   <br/>   'Word2', <br/>   'Word3'

Comment: try the answer posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regx` for this

```
 Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text  '<---- here text is  "Word1 Word2 Word3"
 s = "'" & System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, "\s+", "'," & Chr(13) & "'") & "'"
 '<---- Add ' in the begining and end 
 '<---- Replace n number of white spaces with ','
```

Hence the **output** will be

```
'Word1', 'Word2', 'Word3'
```

Comment: It worked but somehow i get this result 'Word1','Word2','Word3, I have a missing ' @word3 and no wanted comma at the end of word3 // Thanks!!!!